# list of all spring managed beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am using annotation based configuration in my spring project. I inject classes using @Autowired and these classes are annotated with appropriate annotations like @Service, @Component, @Repository, @Controller. I have 2 questions here:

1. Whether I can get an instance of BeanFactory of spring somehow?
2. Can I get a list of all those beans that are managed by spring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inject the context like so:

```
 @Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

That injects the current context into the bean. Since this implements [ListableBeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html), you get the names of all beans using [getBeanDefinitionNames()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinitionNames%28%29)

Comment: Thanx for your help.
One more question sir: can i create bean(just like bean that's autowired) by calling appContext.getBean("name of bean") alongside using annotations?

Comment: Yes, the injected context is exactly the same that is also used to do the autowiring. And autowiring is just a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which eventually calls one of the `appContext.getBean()` methods.

Comment: The magic of Spring is that there is no magic involved. Everything works as you'd expect (well, most of the time ;-)